# use non-standard file descriptors through file objects

Tags: python, io, pipe, nonblocking

#### 1. Can a (blocking) python pipe be wrapped as a file object?

```
>>> p = os.pipe()
# does not block if data available
>>> os.read(p[0], 1024)
b'asdf'
# blocks if no data available
>>> os.read(p[0], 1024)
.... (blocking)
# doesn't block if no data available, but no data requested
>>> os.read(p[0], 1024)
b''
# doesn't block if the write-end is closed
>>> os.close(p[1])
>>> os.read(p[0], 1024)
b''
```

Unfortunately, this file object wrapper isn't working:

```
>>> p = os.pipe()
>>> f = (os.fdopen(p[0], mode="r"), os.fdopen(p[1], mode="w"))
>>> f
(<_io.TextIOWrapper name=3 mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>, <_io.TextIOWrapper name=6 mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
>>> os.write(p[1], b"asdf")
# blocks even if data available
>>> f[0].read(1024)
.... (blocking)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyboardInterrupt
# then, the data no longer exists:
>>> f[0].read(1)
.... (blocking)
# doesn't block if no data available, but no data requested
>>> f[0].read(0)
# doesn't block if the write-end is closed
>>> f[1].close()
>>> f[0].read(1)
```

However, the subprocess module returns a file-object wrapped pipe:

```
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "foobar"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> p.stdout
<_io.BufferedReader name=3>
# contrast to the <_io.TextIOWrapper> object from above
```

But I can't find any details on the constructors of `io.BufferedReader` or `io.RawIOBase`.

*edit: I take the section regarding subprocess back. It only appears to work because the subprocess has terminated, and the write end is closed. Otherwise it suffers the same problems as my `<_io.TextIOWrapper>` wrapper above:*

```
p = subprocess.Popen("cat foobar"; sleep 60, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
p.stdout.read(10240)
.... (blocking)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  KeyboardInterrupt
# now the process is dead
>>> p.stdout.read(1)
b''
>>> p.wait()
-2
```

#### 2. Can non-blocking descriptors be used as file objects?

If a file object is made non-blocking by modifying its file descriptor flags using `fcntl`, is that file object still usable, or do I now have to use the `os.read`, `os.write`, and `os.close` methods?

I briefly tried wrapping a non-blocking pipe in a file object. There are two problems:

1. `BlockingIOError` not raised
2. `read()` (without arguments) raises TypeError

Comment: Have you tried `fcntl`?

Comment: yikes, that was the title of my next question - can't believe I didn't notice till now, but fixed. @RolandSmith : yes, non-blocking descriptors are the second type (part 2) of descriptor I try to wrap into a file object.